# How can I log into Bing.com with C#?

Tags: c#, bing

Well really I guess it would be `https://login.live.com/`, But regardless my goal is to make a windows application that will be able to log into bing.com. Right now I have a button on my windows form that's purpose is to log into bing.com. I found some code on how to log into websites and tried to implement it but to no avail. Right now this is what I have in the button click event:

```
var loginAddress = "https://login.live.com/";
            var loginData = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "username", "myUserName" },
                { "password", "myPassword" }
            };

            var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
            client.Login(loginAddress, loginData);
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "https://login.live.com/");
```

Here is my CookieAwareWebClient class code:

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public void Login(string loginPageAddress, NameValueCollection loginData)
    {
        CookieContainer container;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginData.ToString());
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        container = request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
        CookieContainer = container;
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer container)
    {
        CookieContainer = container;
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the code.....?

Comment: You can't (easily) set IE's cookies.

Comment: @Tim Just takes me to the https://login.live.com/ web page. Not logged in as the user I specify in the code.

Comment: @SLaks what do you suggest I use?

Comment: @winner: There is no easy way to do this.

Comment: Would this work using another browser?